# What is the use of module.parent in node.js? How can I refer to the require()ing module?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I was looking in the [node.js module](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) documentation, and noticed that each module has a property- `module.parent`. I tried to use it, but got burnt by the module caching- `module.parent` only ever seems to the module that *first require()'d it*, irrespective of current context.

So what is the usage of it? Is there any other way for me to get a reference to the *current* require()ing module? Right now I'm wrapping the module in a function, so that it is called like:

```
require("mylibrary")(module)
```

but that seems sub-optimal.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The "parent" is the module that caused the script to be interpreted (and cached), if any:

```
// $ node foo.js
console.log(module.parent); // `null`
```

```
// require('./foo')
console.log(module.parent); // `{ ... }`
```

What you're expecting is the "caller," which Node doesn't retain for you. For that, you'll need the exported function you're currently using to be a closure for the value.

Comment: To add to this answer... I imagine (haven't tried) that this could be one way a module could determine whether it's being run "standalone", via command line, as opposed to being included as part of a bigger app. We have some rake-like modules that can work in both of these contexts, but behave slightly differently depending on the context (like, how they log msgs or emit events might differ). But, we use a different method to determine context: `if(require.main === module) { /* I'm a standalone module */ }`.

Answer (score 29):

There is a workaround for this.  Node adds a module to the module cache before it finishes loading it.  This means that a module can *delete itself* from the module cache while it's loading!  Then every time the module is `require`'d a new instance of the module is loaded.

**Magic.js**

```
console.log('Required by ' + module.parent.filename);
delete require.cache[__filename];
```

**Module1.js**

```
//prints "Required by Module1.js"
require('./Magic');
```

**Module2.js**

```
//prints "Required by Module2.js"
require('./Magic');
```

Of course the side-effect of this is that your module is no longer a singleton, so you have to code `Magic.js` with that in mind.  If you need to store global data you can always keep it in a require()'ed module that doesn't delete itself from the cache.

---

#### Update for 2022

Note the technique described above doesn't work for ES Modules included with `import`. As far as I know there is no good way to detect the importing ES Module.

Comment: Genius! This seems to be an easily overlooked context-awareness integration approach for tooling and libraries, like loggers.

Comment: Delete `require.cache` help me a lot on chaining module requiring! Thanks!