# Node.js run main if called directly; don't if require'd

Tags: node.js

I have a node module that I would like to be callable as a standalone function and also as a library.  If called standalone it needs to parse command line arguments and such.  If required it needs to, well, not.  Can a node file tell how it's called, and if called directly from `node <file>`, execute a different code path than if required?

Comment: Related: [node.js equivalent of python's `if __name__ == '__main__'`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981891/node-js-equivalent-of-pythons-if-name-main)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651945/what-is-the-use-of-module-parent-in-node-js-how-can-i-refer-to-the-requireing

Comment: @Blender yes, this question should be closed as a dupe of that (but not deleted since it asks in perhaps a more searchable way).

Comment: It should be the other way arround with the close votes. Sorry.

Comment: @TheHippo well, no, the answers are over on *that* question.  I don't think it's really important that the one with the more general title is the one that is pointed to, but there's probably lots of meta questions that cover this.