# How to determine in which file function was executed?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to be able to check in log.js file where (file1 or file2) function print_info was executed.

I've tried module.parent.parent.filename but it returns path to file1 even if I'm running file2.

Is it possible in node?

I have these files:

log.js

```
function print_info(data){
   console.log('Function was called in: ', module.parent.parent.filename) //here I'd like to know where function was executed
   console.log(data);
};
```

file1.js

```
var print_info = require('log.js');
print_info(my_data);
```

file2.js

```
var print_info = require('log.js');
print_info(my_data);
```

Comment: Try add `delete require.cache[__filename];` in log.js. Check it [What is the use of module.parent in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651945/what-is-the-use-of-module-parent-in-node-js-how-can-i-refer-to-the-requireing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bad practice, if you need to identify the caller, the calling function should pass an identifier to `print_info`.

i.e. in `file1.js`, write `print_info('file1', my_data)`

If for whatever reason you insist on a "parent approach", you can use stacktrace:

```js
function print_info(data){
   console.log('Function was called in: ');
   var stack = new Error().stack.split('\n');
   console.log(stack);
   console.log(data);
};
```

You can read the value of `stack`, item 0 will be "Error", item 1 will refer to the line of new Error(), item 2 to its parent, and item 3 should be parent.parent.

Or if you are okay with just *printing* the whole stacktrace, you can just do `console.trace(data)`.